# Delaying an ms crm dialog step running

Tags: c#, dialog, dynamics-crm

I have a crm dialog which prints 3 documents. 2 are printed using DocumentCorePack and the other a plugin to print annotations. I need the DCP documents to print first and the plugin to print last. However it seems the plugin works faster and always prints first. Is there a way I can add a delay in the plugins execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delayed execution can only be achieved by a workflow with timeout condition. In this workflow you can insert a custom workflow activity.